# Parameterized inner join

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have two tables named mytest and class what I need to do is to join them by the column id that exists in both table, but the problem is that I need to firstName column be parametrized in order to join the selected firstName, not all the columns that  have the same id with fristName column this is the point I got but I have an error

```
SELECT mytest.firstName,class.name 
FROM mytest 
INNER JOIN class ON mytest.id=class.id 
where fristName=?
```

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1``

```
public List <studentrgister> showcourse(String names) throws Exception {
        List<studentrgister> students = new ArrayList<>();
         String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_student_tracker";
          System.out.println("loding the driver");
          Statement s=null;
        studentrgister mystudent=null;
        Connection myConn = null;
        myConn= DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "webstudent", "webstudent"); 
      System.out.println("username and password is correect");

        PreparedStatement myStmt=null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;
        String  name=names;
try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          System.out.println("driver is loaded");
    String sql="SELECT mytest.firstName,class.name FROM mytest INNER JOIN class ON mytest.id=class.id where mytest.firstName=? " ;
    s =myConn.createStatement();
    s.executeQuery(sql);
    myRs=s.getResultSet();
    if (myRs.next()) {
        String classname = myRs.getString("name");
        int numbername=myRs.getInt("firstName");
        mystudent = new studentrgister(classname,numbername);
        students.add(mystudent);
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("Could not find student id: " );
        }           




        return students;
}
        finally {
            close(myConn,myStmt,null);

        }

    }
```

Comment: You might need to show us the code that triggers the query. Possibly, you are not properly biding the parameter.

Comment: I will post it now

Comment: `where fristName=?`

So the column name is `fristName` or `firstName`?

Comment: its ``firstName``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use parameters in a SQL statement, you need to use a *PreparedStatement*. For example:

```
String sql = "SELECT mytest.firstName,class.name FROM mytest "
 + "INNER JOIN class ON mytest.id=class.id "
 + "where mytest.firstName = ? " ;
PreparedStatement ps = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, "Anne"); // we apply the parameter value
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you that solve the problem with Parameterized inner join but I have this error now ``Invalid value for getInt() - 'Mary'] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'Mary' ``

Comment: I found out, I have to change int numbername to String type
`